# vba excel FileSystemObject readline function does not read a complete line

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am trying to write a macro to automatically import a csv file my workbook. However I met with issue parsing the delimiters, specifically the readline method of the filesystemobject does not read a complete line when called

Example

a line in csv:

```
  1,2,jack,"there can be many boys in the room"3,4,test,n.a
```

what readline extract

```
1,2,jack,"there can be many
```

This causes the sheet to end up like

```
1  |  2 | jack |there can be may
boys in the room| 3 | 4 | test | na
```

Any ideas what might be causing this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Use a hex editor to ensure that there are no unprintable characters in the input stream. Also make sure you are correctly specifying the encoding of the input file.

Comment: You may want to `ReadAll` instead of `ReadLine`, then process the `Split(sAll,vbCrLf)`.

Comment: Could be some hidden char, especially because the FileSystemObject can read until the "newline" char

Comment: use worksheetfunction.Clean() to clear the unprint characters

Comment: @PieterGeerkens As you suspected, as the csv file was created by a linux machine and brought onto window environment, the problem was caused by lf(0x0a) characters littered around the files. Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 1):

The most proper way would be to handle and get rid of unprintable characters, as Pieter Geerkens recommends, or to read everything and split like PatricK recommends. But then, you may end up with having too much pieces again, if there are really some unexpected newlines.

Therefore here is a hint how to make your reading more robust on a, say, semantic level.

The idea is to read a line and to decide if it was a full line:

```
...
var line as String
var lineFinished as boolean

' Loop starts here
  ...
  lineFinished = false
  ...

  ' Read a line, or a piece of it.
  linePiece = a.ReadLine   ' or similar
  ...

  ' Now let's count the number of quotas:
  dim cnt as integer
  cnt = 0
  for i=1 to len(line)
     if mid(line, 0, i) = """" then
        cnt = cnt + 1
     end if
  next

  ' If there is an odd number of quotas, the line is not finished:
  lineFinished = (cnt mod 2 = 0) and (cnt > 0)

  ' If the line is finished, then take it as a full line. Otherwise, add the pieces up.
  if lineFinished then
    lineFinal = linePiece
  else
    lineFinal = lineFinal & linePiece
  end if

  ...
  ' Then, use this place to clean the line from other nasty chars:
  line = replace(line, "\n", "")
  line = replace(line, "\r", "")
  line = replace(line, "\t", "")
  ...

  ' Then, put your lineFinal to the whole string and reset the variable for the next loop.
```

I am aware that replace and counting that way feels very clumsy. But somehow, this is VBA. Like this, you won't need the regex library and you can add up your experience directly to the code by adding lines. If you discover a new character that disturbs, just add it to the replace lines.

One may discuss if it would be better to check the final line for being finished, instead of check the pieces for being only parts of a line. But the one or other way, you may have some uncertainties if you read a very small piece without any quotas at all (therefore the `cnt > 0`). But let's not hope your file is that poisoned ;-)

Good luck.

**EDIT:**

Maybe an even better approach, for the matter of counting, would be to count the number of commas `,`. So, you can rather precisely measure how "complete" your line is already.

Comment: I like the idea of counting the number of commas since the format of the csv is known. Although this does make the program inflexible, I will probably try this if I am unable to find a way to clean the csv text file.

Thanks for the idea ^^